# UML схема React компонента

Tags: reactjs, компоненты, uml, связи, диаграммы

подскажите как должна выглядеть UML схема связей всех компонентов из данного примера:

```
const App = (props) => {

    const components = [
        LeftPanel,
        RightPanel
    ]

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Progressbar />}>
            <ConfigProvider>
                {React.createElement(components[props.index])}
            </ConfigProvider>
        </Suspense>
    );
}
```

какие именно типы связей должны быть, а то я совсем запутался с этим :)